# Regex for matching all text inside opening and closing angle brackets of img tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to create regex that match the text inside opening and its matching closing angle brackets of html img tag with PHP. Let's say I have the html text in variable $searchThis

```
$searchThis = "<html><div></div><img src='/relative/path/img1.png'/></div>
<img src='/relative/path/img2.png'/><div></div></div>
<img src='/relative/path/img3.png'/><ul><li></li></ul></html>";
```

I want to match the content in  tags which ellipsis is substitution for. The result must be the following matches:

```
src='/relative/path/img1.png'
src='/relative/path/img2.png'
src='/relative/path/img3.png'
```

This is how I imagine the pattern should be and which actually doesn't work for me:

```
$pattern = "<img([^\/]+)\/>";
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to parse HTML using regular expression. Use XPath or some similar XML access approach instead. Have a look at [this collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml/3577662#3577662).

Comment: You want to get the output only by regex? what about simplehtmldom?

Comment: Ok, but I won't use anything out of the PHP standard library.

Answer (score 2):

**Try:**

```
preg_match_all("`<img (.*)/>`Uis", $searchThis, $results);
print_r($results);
```

Printing the structure of `$results` will show you its content.

**Note:** If you wish to be more accurate, I would suggest you to include `src=` in your search and go until the closing quote mark, in order to to only select the image address. Then you can add the missing text (`src=`) afterwards. 

This way, you still gets the relative path, even when your image tag doesn't look like expected (i.e. there are other stuffs in the tag like `alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"`).

Comment: I don't know. I alway use the character ` to quote the string pattern, so I can add stuffs like U, i, s to tune the search options.

Comment: Any non-alphanumeric character can be used as a regex delimiter, although I must admit I've never seen the backtick used for this purpose before.

Comment: I don't remember where I saw it for the first time. But since, I only use this character. I looks more clear to me. Maybe I am juste used to.

Comment: Let's say HTML is like this: `<html><img\nsrc='/relative/path/img1.png'/></html>` (new line after `<img`) Will this regex still work?

Comment: No, because I put a space between `<img` and `(.*)`. You can remove the space, then you will get everything between `<img` and the next `(.*)`. After you get the match, there is still some work to do: remove trailing spaces, if any, newlines, etc. Do you need more details on why I put `U`, `i` and `s`? and on why there is `(.*)` in the pattern?

Comment: i - case insensitive, s - single line. What's about U?

Comment: @Jean: I completely understand how to make it work using regex but what I meant to say is regex approach has a huge risk while parsing HTML.

Comment: @anubhava Of course you do. Sorry, I mis-looked who was posting the comment. I agree with you, but 0xc0deguru says: regex only.

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU the `U` option means ungreedy. It is to force the regex to start looking from `<img` and stop at the first `/>` encountered. Try it without the `U` and you will see the difference. You may very well get the whole HTML code starting from the first `<img` up to the last `/>` encountered.

Comment: I got it. Like "?" but in "global scope".

Answer (score 2):

Never try to parse HTML with regex. For parsing HTML use [**DOM Parser**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Consider code like this:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<html><div></div><img src='/relative/path/img1.png'/></div>
<img src='/relative/path/img2.png'/><div></div></div>
<img src='/relative/path/img3.png'/><ul><li></li></ul></html>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//img");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $src = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue;
    echo "src='$src'\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
src='/relative/path/img1.png'
src='/relative/path/img2.png'
src='/relative/path/img3.png'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that in the standard PHP library there is a DOM Parser. I don't use PHP often and that's not my strong.

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU: Even I have not coded in PHP for my work. Its only while answering questions on SO I learnt it :P

Answer (score 0):

Example Parsing With [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
    <?php
    include("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = str_get_html("<html><div></div><img src='/relative/path/img1.png'/></div>
    <img src='/relative/path/img2.png'/><div></div></div>
    <img src='/relative/path/img3.png'/><ul><li></li></ul></html>");

    // Find all images
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
           echo $element->src . '<br>';
    ?>
```

Comment: It seems the most elegant solution but I have to use only the standard library :) Thanx